# Grep command doesn't not print the correct line

Tags: unix, grep

I am using `grep -Prnz`, because of the `-z` flag, it doesn't print the correct line - it always prints line number 1.

Is it possible to print just the first line of that multi-line match?

```
hello 
hello
bye { 

}

hello
hello
```

command: `grep -Prnz file.txt 'bye\s*\{\s*\}'`

expected output: `file.txt:3:bye {`

actual output: `file.txt:1:bye {`

Comment: What is your input file and what are you trying to match? Show us an input file and expected output

Comment: @Inian updated question

Comment: If you don't have to use grep, [pcregrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pcregrep) with the `-M -n` options handles this OK. `-M` means multiline.

Comment: `grep -noPz  'bye\s*\{(?=\s*\})' file.txt` is closest I can get based on your question.. and it will indeed give line number as `1`... with `-z` entire file is single string, no concept of lines... `grep -Prnz file.txt 'bye\s*\{\s*\}'` will give error and why do you need `-r` for single file input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pcregrep -M -n` solves this problem. There is no possibility to do it using `grep -zn`